# Save date fromJQuery datepicker in table

Tags: jquery, jsp, datepicker

In my JSP page am adding date picker in each row of table. I need to save the date to database on selecting a new date. Following is the code I did:

```
<table id="track" width="100%">
 <tbody>
   <c:forEach items="${itemList}" var="items" varStatus ="status">
      <tr>
        <td>
          ${items.id}         
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type='text' id="creationDate_${items.id}"  name="creationDate_${items.id}"  class="creationDatePicker" value = "${items.createdOn}" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
       </tr>
  </c:forEach>
```

And my JSP is:

```
$('.creationDatePicker').datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function (date) {
      // Code to update date in table.
    }
});
```

How can I get the corresponding id of the item on date change?

Answer (score 0):

You can place hiddenfield beside datepicker td and add selected date in that input hiddenfield.

Now on saving you can access Id and selected date.

```
$('.creationDatePicker').datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function (date) {
    var id=$(this).closest('tr > td:eq(0)').html();
    //Set selected date to input hiddenfield here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are setting input `id="creationDate_${items.id}"`, just remove 'creationDate_' from id value and get item id like below

```
$('.creationDatePicker').datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function (date) {
      var inputId = $(this).attr('id');
      var itemId = inputId.replace('creationDate_','');
      alert(itemId); // this is the item id required
    }
});
```